# When did Jo Grant see the Doctor recover from the cold after a temperature rise?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Planet of the Daleks*, Jo mentions that this isn't the first time she's seen the Doctor enter a coma due to being cold. She claims that a sudden rise in temperature allowed him to recover the last time.

When was this? I assume this was a known adventure (be it on-screen or in another medium), since the [TARDIS Wikia](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_of_the_Daleks#The_Doctor) says, "The Doctor once again goes into a catatonic state in extreme cold, but reawakens after an extreme rise in temperature". I was disappointed that this comment contained no hyperlink to a relevant previous story, even though such comments often do. I also got nowhere googling it, short of this story.

Comment: I suspect the TARDIS wikia got that statement from Jo’s statement in *Planet of the Daleks*.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Season 8, The Daemons, part 2

http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p01bb3lq/p01bb3fz

He's even a bit sweaty...

EDIT to add **TARDIS.WIKIA** quote and link...

*"Garvin holds both of them at gunpoint and moves them outside, just as the ground starts to shake. Garvin fires up at something gigantic, but is engulfed in a fireball. The heat wave extends even into the village, knocking Jo and Yates down, just as the Doctor awakens with a start."*

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_D%C3%A6mons_%28TV_story%29